# Resizing dialog issues with MFC and status bars

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog, statusbar, dynamiclayout

The minimum size of my dialog does not factor in the size of the status bar.

In `OnInitDialog` I create the status bar and add it to the dynamic layout:

```
m_StatusBar.Create(this);
m_StatusBar.SetIndicators(&indicators_msa[0], 3);
m_StatusBar.SetPaneInfo(0, ID_INDICATOR_PROGRESS, SBPS_NORMAL, 100);
m_StatusBar.SetPaneInfo(1, ID_INDICATOR_TEXT, SBPS_STRETCH, 100);
m_StatusBar.SetPaneInfo(2, ID_INDICATOR_CONGREGATION_NAME, SBPS_NORMAL, 150);
m_StatusBar.SetPaneText(0, L"");
m_StatusBar.SetPaneText(1, L"");
m_StatusBar.SetPaneText(2, theApp.MSAToolsInterface().GetLocalCongregationName());

RepositionBars(AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, 0);

m_StatusProgressBar.Create(L"", 100, 100, true, 0, &m_StatusBar);

m_pDynamicLayout->AddItem(m_StatusBar.GetSafeHwnd(),
    CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveVertical(100),
    CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeHorizontal(100));
```

This bit does work. But when I try to reduce the size of the dialog it reduces to the original dialog size without taking into account the status bar:

[image]

I don't expect it to hide the status bar:

[image]

My `CDialog` inherits from a custom class which already implements:

```
void CResizingDialog::OnGetMinMaxInfo(MINMAXINFO* lpMMI)
{
    // Set the minimum window size to initial size.
    if (!m_rcInit.IsRectEmpty()) {
        lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.x = m_rcInit.Width();
        lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.y = m_rcInit.Height();

        if (m_bLimitToHorizontalResizing)
            lpMMI->ptMaxTrackSize.y = m_rcInit.Height();
    }

    __super::OnGetMinMaxInfo(lpMMI);
}
```

`m_rcInit` is defined in `OnInitDialog`. I realize that the base class has no knowledge of a status bar. So maybe I have to add the size of a status bar to the default height before setting `ptMinTrackSize.y`

?

It seems if I physically (in IDE) make the dialog taller to allow for the toolbar at top AND statusbar then things are better. Most odd.

Comment: Are you (re-)setting the `m_rcInit` member in your derived class `OnInitDialog`, after adding the status bar and allowing for that?

Comment: @AdrianMole no. But I understood that the min/max is only ever set once anyway. However, I can confirm that if I add a figure (pulled 50 out of the hat) to min y that it behaves better. It is as if the dialog is not aware that a toolbar was added at the top and status bar at the bottom. Added for that makes it better. But I don't like fudging 50. Ad I don't think we can re-do min/max. Won't it be too late?

Comment: Hmm. The documentation says, *The framework calls this member function whenever Windows needs to know the maximized position or dimensions, or the minimum or maximum tracking size.*. Now, whether or not it is called when changes are made to the `CMFCDynamicLayout`, I don't know. Try adding a debug `Beep(1000,100)` (or some such) to your version of it...

Comment: @AdrianMole I worked out the issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion by @AdrianMole in the comments made me realise what the issue was. This is how  resolved it:

1. I added a new `bool m_bRestoreWindowPositionImmediately` variable to the `CResizingDialog` class.
2. The constructor was updated to include this variable, defaulting to `true` for backward compatibility.
3. `OnInitDialog` was updated:

```
BOOL CResizingDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    __super::OnInitDialog();

    // Save Initial window size to m_rcInit
    RecalculateSize();

    if (m_bRestoreWindowPositionImmediately)
    {
        RestoreWindowPosition();
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

4. Now I modified the parent `CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg` contructor to pass `false` for the new variable.
5. Finally, I modified the `CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::OnInitDialog` to do this:

```
BOOL CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    // Create toolbar
    // Create status bar

    RecalculateSize(); // Resets the m_rcInit
    RestoreWindowPosition(); // Now restore
}
```

Now the `m_rcInit` has the correct size, with toolbar and statusbar inplace. And this is at the default window size. Calling `RestoreWindowPosition` at this time works correctly and the window no longer resizes too small and behaves exactly as it should do.